# How can I make sure that only thoroughly tested changes make it into the master branch in git, without cherry picking commits from development?

Tags: git

We have two main branches here, `master` and `development`, and feature/bugfix branches come off of `development`. The issue we're having here is that we can't just merge `development` into `master` when doing a production deployment, because it's not guaranteed that those changes are thoroughly tested. What we've been doing is cherry picking changes from `development` into `master`, but that's a nightmare because sometimes changes depend on prior changes, so the code could wind up with compile errors if for instance I have PRs 1 and 2 and 2 contains a reference to a function added in 1, but we only want to deploy 2. This is especially bad because this is a VB.NET WebForms project, so compile errors don't always show up until runtime...

Comment: Use pull requests?

Comment: Do your testing on your production branch. Test and deploy the same artefacts.

Comment: @AntP: What production branch?  Did you mean "create a production branch?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, I meant the branch that is being deployed into production. In this case, master.

Comment: @AntP: Didn't the OP say he wanted the code tested *first,* before it makes it to the master branch?

Comment: @ekolis: Have a look here: https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes - I am challenging that premise, which is why I posted a terse comment instead of an answer.

Comment: A "staging" branch is probably a better idea.  The code can be tested there, before it is pushed to master.

Comment: "Cherry picking commits" is a fancy way of saying "having Git write new code for me at merge-time which MIGHT be correct (no guauratees)".

Comment: As Robert says, a staging branch and a very good set of regression tests is probably your best bet.

Comment: create a staging based on master branch and development branch base on staging one. so you can keep working on devp one. pull change to staging one, throughly test it once done merge it to master one

Answer (score 4):

To do that, you're going to need at least one more branch.  Call it "staging," if you like.  This is where you will push feature changes to, for testing.  Once you're satisfied that the changes will "take," you can push them to the master branch.

Depending on how big your team is, and the level of rigor required (not all software is equal; financial and medical software require more rigorous processes), you might want to adopt a more robust model.  You can study models like [Gitflow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) to see how other teams do it:

[image]

But only adopt this level of complexity if your software demands it.

Comment: Hmm, a staging branch makes sense - we've been using our development branch for that purpose. But wouldn't we run into the same issue as before, just separated by another branch? That is, how would we guarantee that the staging branch contains only code that is safe to deploy to production, if it's a testing branch? And if we can't guarantee that, wouldn't we need to cherry-pick changes to make sure that only the ones we want to deploy get deployed?

Comment: One way to do that would be to merge your production branch into your staging branch, before applying your features to the staging branch.  Your staging branch would then become the basis for a new release; once you've determined that all of your features are properly merged and all the tests pass, you can then merge the staging branch back into the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a new branch off of `development`. Might as well call it
   `staging`, like in the sibling answer.
2. `development` continues as usual, of course; merge new features and
   whatnot to your heart’s desire
3. Only merge critical fixes to `staging` (showstoppers, low-risk
   changes)

   - Merge changes to `staging` into `development`
4. Let `staging` cook for however long it takes for you to test it
5. Merge `staging` to `master` when it’s ready
6. Either delete `staging` or let it sit around
7. The next time you need `staging`: either create it (if deleted) or
   fast-forward it to `develop`

#### Concrete example

You have five days until some release. So you make `staging`, ask people
to test, and make sure that incoming PRs are redirected to `staging` if
they fix something critical to the next release.

#### Let it cook

The only way to test the state of the code is to slow down (only
critical fixes) and test it—you won’t be able to test a code base which
gets new features every day. And that means that you either have to:

- Freeze most activity on the `development` branch
- Create a new branch like `staging`